# Ambiguous column name 'countryname'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a procedure like below

```
BEGIN 
SELECT distinct countryname, countryid 
 FROM Country c 
  Inner join Cause cs on cs.CountryName = c.CountryName
 END
```

It is displaying error message like "Ambiguous column name 'countryname'."

I want to fetch distinct rows on the basis of countryname and countryid. 
Please help...

Comment: Use `c.CountryName` instead of `countryname` in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: use this : SELECT distinct c.countryname, c.countryid 
 FROM Country c  Inner join Cause cs on cs.CountryName = c.CountryName

Comment: Use alias_name.column_name in select list because countryname column may present in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your query the same column-name is available on multiple tables the Interpreter needs to know which column is meant.

In your case you should write your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.countryname, countryid 
FROM Country c INNER JOIN Cause cs 
    ON cs.CountryName = c.CountryName
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT cs.countryname, countryid 
FROM Country c INNER JOIN Cause cs 
    ON cs.CountryName = c.CountryName
```

> Suggestions:
>
> - You may want to specify the alias on *all* columns always
> - Design your model to be joinable on unique integer or guid indexes, avoid joining on "countrynames" unless you can guarantee 100% that there will never be spelling errors (and even then it's bad design).

Answer (score 2):

You shall specify table in select. As example:

```
BEGIN 
SELECT distinct c.countryname, c.countryid 
 FROM Country c 
  Inner join Cause cs on cs.CountryName = c.CountryName
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `alias` for `tables` make sure that the fields for each tables are represented by their respective alias. 
For example you have used alias `c` for `country` table and `cs` for `cause`, so in order to use any columns from `country` table use `c.column_name`.
Your error message is displayed because there might be same column name in both table and the `sql-server` doesn't know which column from which table are you referring to.

So your code should be like

```
BEGIN 
SELECT distinct c.countryname, c.countryid 
 FROM Country c 
  Inner join Cause cs on cs.CountryName = c.CountryName
 END
```